# The difference between "given that" and "provided that" (CAE book reference)

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I don't understand the difference between "given that" and "provided that".

> The tour wasn't as pleasant as we thought it would be, **given that** the
>   coach broke down on the way.

[Source: CAE Book]

1. Why can't I use *provided that* in place of *given that* in the above sentence?
2. What's the difference between *given that* and *provided that*?

Comment: _Given that_ [presupposes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf) its complement clause, whereas _provided that_ does not, but rather leaves the matter hypothetical. Presupposition is one kind of semantic relation between clauses; [there are others](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/predtypes.pdf).

Comment: [“given that”, “if”, “providing that”, or “assuming”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/34618/11458) on ELL

Answer (score 5):

*Given that* in this sense really just means *because*. The above sentence means:

> The tour wasn't as pleasant as we thought it would be **because** the coach broke down on the way.

*Provided that* means that some condition has to be met in order for something else to be true. An example might be:

> We will have a pleasant tour *provided that* the coach does not break down.

Here, *a pleasant tour* will only be true if the condition *the coach does not break down* is met.

Comment: Does 'given that' always mean because? Can we also use as long as in the above example instead of provided that? For example, We'll have a pleasant tour as long as the coach does not break down.

Answer (score 4):

given that means knowing about or considering a particular thing ....
In this case ...

The tour wasn't as pleasant as we thought it would be, **given that** the coach broke down on the way.

It means....
The tour wasn't as pleasant as we thought it would be, **considering that** the coach broke down on the way.

whereas, '**provided that**' is used to replace **if/only if** 
eg. **provided that** the coach doesn't break down, our trip would be pleasant.

it means..
**only if** the coach doesn't break down, our trip would be pleasant.

(PS: I'm giving my CAE exam the next month )

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. madhurima, while your answer is fitting, this site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer seems purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.